# nodejs cannot find module, works on one server but not another

Tags: node.js, npm

I have some code that is working on two different servers, and after trying to move it to a third, it is bombing and for the life of me I can't see why. The specific module is node-memcached (by 3rd-Eden) but since it works in multiple other locations, I'm not sure that is relevant. The only difference between the 3 servers is that I'm trying to update to node 0.10 on this new one, whereas 0.6 is on both of the others.

This is the error I'm seeing:

```
module.js:337
    throw new Error("Cannot find module '" + request + "'");
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'Memcached'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:337:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:359:17)
    at require (module.js:375:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/net/somepath/myproj/CCDataAccess.js:3:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:353:32)
    at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:359:17)
```

I have memcached installed within the project like so:

`cd /net/somepath/myproj/`

`npm install memcached`

And using `npm list` on the same dir I can see it listed there

```
/net/somepath/myproj
├─┬ memcached@0.2.8
│ ├─┬ hashring@0.0.8
│ │ ├── bisection@0.0.3
│ │ └── simple-lru-cache@0.0.1
│ └─┬ jackpot@0.0.6
│   └── retry@0.6.0
```

The actual require statement for memcached is nested about 3 files deep from the startup js, but the actual call is this:

`var Memcached = require('Memcached');`

At this point I'm not sure what to try next to make this work. Any advice, guidance or even maybe a solution would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the [memcached](https://www.npmjs.org/package/memcached) npm page

```
var Memcached = require('memcached');
var memcached = new Memcached(Server locations, options);
```

Try without the uppercase M

have you also done a

```
npm install
```

in the project directory?

Comment: Well color me surprised, either old node is not case sensitive, or windows is not case sensitive! Changing the case from Memcached to memcached (a simple typo) worked. Thanks KCACO!